# How can be personalised the standard login/authentication process of salesforce?

Tags: oauth2, authentication

I'm trying to understand if is possible to override the standard login/authentication processo of salesforce.

I need to add custom logic when is triggered the login/authentication process of salesforce  from
- Community
- SDK Mobile salesforce
- Embedded login

some external systems use the **oauth2/authorize** service to authenticate. The request is to add some logic, that would create the user just in time, and than authenticate it if the user exist in some other system (with password e details present in another system).

I made search online, and tried to study the the salesforce documentation but i didn't understood if this can be done, and an example on how to do it.

Anyone can address me to understand if the authorization process can be overriden/extended for mine usecase?

thanks in advance.

**Edit ------ 2020010814:52**

I try to add some more information on the particular use-case that i'm trying to understand if feasible for all channels (Community, Mobile, Embedded login).
Before the authorization is executed, i need to check

1. If the user exist, if so, than let execute the standard salesforce authentication process
2. if the user doesn't exist check if the user exist in a backed system. If so, create a user on Salesforce and than let start the authentication process
3. otherwise authentication fails

For the community i can create a custom login, but i don't know how to do a similar approach for  embedded login, e for Mobile SDK. The best guess i made, is to extend the Salesforce authorization process, but i din't found if this can be done.

Hope to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to customize the authentication process, salesforce provides [login flows](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_login_flow.htm&type=5)

Login flows allow you to declaratively add post authentication logics to your login flow. They are profile based and can be helpful for your use case.

You can easily add a flow that can invoke your service and you can block user from authenticating as well based on your business use case.

The other thing that you can do is implement SAML between salesforce and the system you are login and use JIT (Just in time provisioning) for community users.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, i need to add custom logic before the authentication occurs, i need to modify/extend the controller of the oauth2/authorize service , and login flows doesn't apply.

I read about SAML JIT, but unfortunately is not the case (it wold be perfect if another system would work as identity provider for the context).

Comment: More specifically, i need to check if the user exist already in salesforce,
- if so, than let execute the standard salesforce authentication process
- if the user doesn't exist, than check if the user exist in a backend system (database), if so, create a user on salesforce , and that let start the authentication process
- otherwise authentication fails

Comment: You cannot extend the authorize service of Salesforce platform. You can add some logic though using those flows or add logic for registration handler during user registration

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.